# java- Cycle between two arrays using for and while loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am having difficulty with my program. Some help would be appreciated. 
I have 3 arrays, 2 that store emotions and 1 that stores names. The 2 names in the names array correspond to each of the two emotion arrays. I want to use a for loop and a while loop to change these for each name. Currently what I have is :

```
public static int [] showhunger(int [] i, int [] m,String [] x)
    {   String ans = "yes";
        for (int j=0;j<names.length;j++)
        {   while(ans.equals("yes")||ans.equals("Yes")||ans.equals("y")||ans.equals("Y"))
            {   if (i[0]<=-1)
                {   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Stop "+x[j]);
                }
            ans=JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Feed "+x[j]+"?");
            if (ans.equals("yes")||ans.equals("Yes")||ans.equals("y")||ans.equals("Y"))
                {   i[0]-=1;
                }
            }
        }return i;
    }
```

I cannot get the for loop to cycle between the two integer arrays. Also I'd like to know how I can return both arrays

Comment: you cant return two arrays. But you can return an object with that for example.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina could you show me how, and also how the assignment would look, after it has been returned?

Comment: or you can change the arrays in your method  (you do it).

Comment: you dont use m. and can you explain " for loop to cycle between the two integer arrays"  ? you only loop the "names" array

Comment: Yes integer array m is the other emotion state which corresponds to x[1]. So I want to check for m with the second name, the second time the for loop runs

Comment: could you explain with some phrases, what are i, m, x (better names ?), and show some examples of values, and describe what happens with the user ? thanks

Comment: @duldi The task is unclear, and your code doesn't help with understanding *what you are trying to do*. Please edit your question to include details.

Answer (score 0):

your code should have more comments inside, to explain your loops .

you can not return 2 arrays, but if you change them in your method, they are changed.

if you want to really return something:
you can return an object with that for example

```
public class bundle
{
public int A[];
public int B[];
}

public static bundle showhunger(...)
{
// ...

bundle bdl=new bundle();
bdl.A=new int[10];
bdl.B=new int[10];
// populate

return bdl;
}
```

Comment: I will give this a  go and...return the result. But in all seriousness,  I will attempt this

Comment: or just use an ``int[][]`` as follows: ``return new int[][]{i, m};``